# Android: Home logo not clickable?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-homebutton

I am trying to make app's logo clickable using AppCompatActivity.  The logo is in the home location of the toolbar and left-aligned.  The logo displays correctly but the logo is not clickable.  What am I missing here?

Activity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_s_logo_48x48);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
         switch (item.getItemId()) {
         case R.id.home:
             Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This is the homepage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
             toast1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL,0,0);
             toast1.show();
             return true;             
      default:
         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }
}
```

toolbar.xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/home"
    android:title="@string/action_logo"
    android:contentDescription="@string/action_logo"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_s_logo_48x48"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use another way to handle your home `ImageButton` clicked like this

```
ImageButton ivHome = (ImageButton) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.home);

ivHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log("TAG","Home image click");
            }
});
```

**====

OR**

You can use `setNavigationIcon` for your `Toolbar` (it will display like your current home button)
To do that

1.Create toolbar xml like this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

2.Change toolbar navigation icon in your `Activity`

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_home_icon));
```

3. Handle event when click

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         Log.d("TAG", "home clicked");
     }
});
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.  Do I assume correctly that I could use similar code for a TouchListener?

Comment: I tried the code you recommended and unfortunately it did not work.  The icon seems frozen, like it is not enabled to accept clicks.  When the overflow icon is clicked, a gray shadow appears momentarily to show that the icon has been clicked.  When I click the home icon, nothing happens.  Any thoughts?

Comment: inside onClick, you should add some `logcat` for check, maybe the Toast can cause problem. then tell me does the locat show or not

Comment: I replaced the Toast with an Intent on the onClick section and still no luck.

Comment: Can you change your `ImageView` to `Button` or `ImageButton`. It can easy to handle click event

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99081/discussion-between-phan-vn-linh-and-ajw).